# Guidance with jquery flot line chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I am attempting to display a simple line chart with points using jquery flot. I am not sure where I am going wrong but I cant get any points to show up. Here is what I am doing.

```
var visits = <?php echo json_encode($visits); ?>;
var views = <?php echo json_encode($pageViews); ?>;
var dates = <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?>;
$('#site_statistics').css({
    height: '180px',
    width: '100%'
});

$.plot($('#site_statistics'),[
        { label: 'Visits', data: visits },
        { label: 'Pageviews', data: views }
    ], {
    grid:{
        hoverable:true,
        backgroundColor:'transparent'
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: 'time',
        timeformat:'%m/%d/%y',
        minTickSize: [1,'day'],
        min: (new Date(dates[0])).getTime(),
        max: (new Date(dates[30])).getTime()
    },
    yaxis: {
        mode:'number',
        tickSize:1,
        min: 0,
        tickColor:'#fff'
    },
    legend: {
        position:'ne',
        backgroundOpacity:0
    },
    series: {
        lines: {show:true},
        points: {show:true}
    }
});
```

This is the result I am getting.

[image]

I have verified that my arrays have data through console.log() so for some reason (probably something simple that I am missing) the plugin wont pull the data into the chart. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT

Per request Here is the data being used for views

```
[{"09-20-2016":"2654"},{"09-21-2016":"2430"},{"09-22-2016":"2217"},{"09-23-2016":"2047"},{"09-24-2016":"2152"},{"09-25-2016":"2502"},{"09-26-2016":"2234"},{"09-27-2016":"2020"},{"09-28-2016":"1978"},{"09-29-2016":"2080"},{"09-30-2016":"1632"},{"10-01-2016":"1934"},{"10-02-2016":"2210"},{"10-03-2016":"2068"},{"10-04-2016":"1738"},{"10-05-2016":"1787"},{"10-06-2016":"1694"},{"10-07-2016":"1583"},{"10-08-2016":"1906"},{"10-09-2016":"1936"},{"10-10-2016":"2188"},{"10-11-2016":"1892"},{"10-12-2016":"2036"},{"10-13-2016":"1970"},{"10-14-2016":"2044"},{"10-15-2016":"2109"},{"10-16-2016":"2425"},{"10-17-2016":"2554"},{"10-18-2016":"2332"},{"10-19-2016":"2177"},{"10-20-2016":"723"}]
```

Data for visits

```
[{"09-20-2016":"1013"},{"09-21-2016":"871"},{"09-22-2016":"911"},{"09-23-2016":"845"},{"09-24-2016":"924"},{"09-25-2016":"1028"},{"09-26-2016":"877"},{"09-27-2016":"755"},{"09-28-2016":"793"},{"09-29-2016":"867"},{"09-30-2016":"747"},{"10-01-2016":"913"},{"10-02-2016":"1023"},{"10-03-2016":"971"},{"10-04-2016":"918"},{"10-05-2016":"793"},{"10-06-2016":"815"},{"10-07-2016":"813"},{"10-08-2016":"954"},{"10-09-2016":"1047"},{"10-10-2016":"1097"},{"10-11-2016":"938"},{"10-12-2016":"1022"},{"10-13-2016":"915"},{"10-14-2016":"1024"},{"10-15-2016":"1168"},{"10-16-2016":"1174"},{"10-17-2016":"1086"},{"10-18-2016":"1106"},{"10-19-2016":"1059"},{"10-20-2016":"364"}]
```

Data for dates

```
[["09-20-2016"],["09-21-2016"],["09-22-2016"],["09-23-2016"],["09-24-2016"],["09-25-2016"],["09-26-2016"],["09-27-2016"],["09-28-2016"],["09-29-2016"],["09-30-2016"],["10-01-2016"],["10-02-2016"],["10-03-2016"],["10-04-2016"],["10-05-2016"],["10-06-2016"],["10-07-2016"],["10-08-2016"],["10-09-2016"],["10-10-2016"],["10-11-2016"],["10-12-2016"],["10-13-2016"],["10-14-2016"],["10-15-2016"],["10-16-2016"],["10-17-2016"],["10-18-2016"],["10-19-2016"],["10-20-2016"]]
```

Comment: would you mind posting some sample data for dates, visits and views that is being fed into the charts?

Comment: I have added the data being used for views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that your date format in view section is not inline with the accepted format.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var viewsList = [{
    "09-20-2016": "2654"
  }, {
    "09-21-2016": "2430"
  }, {
    "09-22-2016": "2217"
  }, {
    "09-23-2016": "2047"
  }, {
    "09-24-2016": "2152"
  }, {
    "09-25-2016": "2502"
  }, {
    "09-26-2016": "2234"
  }, {
    "09-27-2016": "2020"
  }, {
    "09-28-2016": "1978"
  }, {
    "09-29-2016": "2080"
  }, {
    "09-30-2016": "1632"
  }, {
    "10-01-2016": "1934"
  }, {
    "10-02-2016": "2210"
  }, {
    "10-03-2016": "2068"
  }, {
    "10-04-2016": "1738"
  }, {
    "10-05-2016": "1787"
  }, {
    "10-06-2016": "1694"
  }, {
    "10-07-2016": "1583"
  }, {
    "10-08-2016": "1906"
  }, {
    "10-09-2016": "1936"
  }, {
    "10-10-2016": "2188"
  }, {
    "10-11-2016": "1892"
  }, {
    "10-12-2016": "2036"
  }, {
    "10-13-2016": "1970"
  }, {
    "10-14-2016": "2044"
  }, {
    "10-15-2016": "2109"
  }, {
    "10-16-2016": "2425"
  }, {
    "10-17-2016": "2554"
  }, {
    "10-18-2016": "2332"
  }, {
    "10-19-2016": "2177"
  }, {
    "10-20-2016": "723"
  }];

  var visits = [{
    "09-20-2016": "1013"
  }, {
    "09-21-2016": "871"
  }, {
    "09-22-2016": "911"
  }, {
    "09-23-2016": "845"
  }, {
    "09-24-2016": "924"
  }, {
    "09-25-2016": "1028"
  }, {
    "09-26-2016": "877"
  }, {
    "09-27-2016": "755"
  }, {
    "09-28-2016": "793"
  }, {
    "09-29-2016": "867"
  }, {
    "09-30-2016": "747"
  }, {
    "10-01-2016": "913"
  }, {
    "10-02-2016": "1023"
  }, {
    "10-03-2016": "971"
  }, {
    "10-04-2016": "918"
  }, {
    "10-05-2016": "793"
  }, {
    "10-06-2016": "815"
  }, {
    "10-07-2016": "813"
  }, {
    "10-08-2016": "954"
  }, {
    "10-09-2016": "1047"
  }, {
    "10-10-2016": "1097"
  }, {
    "10-11-2016": "938"
  }, {
    "10-12-2016": "1022"
  }, {
    "10-13-2016": "915"
  }, {
    "10-14-2016": "1024"
  }, {
    "10-15-2016": "1168"
  }, {
    "10-16-2016": "1174"
  }, {
    "10-17-2016": "1086"
  }, {
    "10-18-2016": "1106"
  }, {
    "10-19-2016": "1059"
  }, {
    "10-20-2016": "364"
  }];

  var dates = [
    ["09-20-2016"],
    ["09-21-2016"],
    ["09-22-2016"],
    ["09-23-2016"],
    ["09-24-2016"],
    ["09-25-2016"],
    ["09-26-2016"],
    ["09-27-2016"],
    ["09-28-2016"],
    ["09-29-2016"],
    ["09-30-2016"],
    ["10-01-2016"],
    ["10-02-2016"],
    ["10-03-2016"],
    ["10-04-2016"],
    ["10-05-2016"],
    ["10-06-2016"],
    ["10-07-2016"],
    ["10-08-2016"],
    ["10-09-2016"],
    ["10-10-2016"],
    ["10-11-2016"],
    ["10-12-2016"],
    ["10-13-2016"],
    ["10-14-2016"],
    ["10-15-2016"],
    ["10-16-2016"],
    ["10-17-2016"],
    ["10-18-2016"],
    ["10-19-2016"],
    ["10-20-2016"]
  ];
  //Format the data into Flot compatabile data.
  var viewData = [];
  viewsList.forEach(function(views) {
    for (var view in views) {
      if (views.hasOwnProperty(view)) {
        views[view] = parseInt(views[view], 10);
        viewData.push([Date.parse(view), views[view]]);
      }
    }
  });

  $('#site_statistics').css({
    height: '180px',
    width: '99%'
  });

  $.plot($('#site_statistics'), [{
    label: 'Pageviews',
    data: viewData
  }], {
    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    xaxis: {
      mode: 'time',
      timeformat: '%m-%d-%y',
      minTickSize: [1, 'day'],
      min: (new Date(dates[0])).getTime(),
      max: (new Date(dates[30])).getTime()
    },
    yaxis: {
      mode: 'number',
      tickSize: 1000,
      min: 0,

      tickColor: '#fff'
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'ne',
      backgroundOpacity: 0
    },
    series: {
      lines: {
        show: true
      },
      points: {
        symbol: "circle",
        fillColor: "#058DC7"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>

<div id="site_statistics"></div>
```

Comment: which part of the views data is wrong? I have removed the date formatting so it is in the form of YYYMMDD. Do I still need to change the formatting?

Comment: ok, its working and the line is showing up in chrome but not firefox. Also have to figure out what is messing with the legend as it looks the same as my screenshot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a Date.parse method and it doesnt work in Firefox when the date format is MM-DD-YYYY it should be MM/DD/YYYY. Here it the codepen link http://codepen.io/jsreekanth/pen/YGdzZP